# Laptop/mobile device in countries with Sharia

Tags: legal, culture, religion, iran, cultural-awareness

I'm traveling to Iran and i need to bring my laptop.

For western standards I do not have anything illegal on my hard drive but since I'm not familiar with the Sharia I'm a little bit paranoid.

1. Is it dangerous to have, for example, holiday pictures of girls in bikinis or similar on your laptop? Is it common that laptops get searched or am I just paranoid?
2. If that is dangerous, how should I proceed? I need to take my laptop with me. Should I encrypt everything? Given the fact that browsing the internet already caches maybe dangerous pictures and it is very hard to be sure that one has deleted all of them, how should I clean my laptop?

Comment: It's common to frame things in these terms but I am not sure that notions like “sharia” or “Western standards” bring much clarity. If that's OK with you, it might be more productive to simply ask about Iran and be very specific about the type of material you are thinking about.

Comment: @Annoyed: I thought that this would've been a to specific question but i have no problem with asking a more specific question. Although i mention Iran and bikini pictures as specific examples. The problem is more like: I do not even know EVERYTHING that is on my laptop (cache, i borrowed to friend ..). I'm sure there is nothing illegal for western standards (e.g. there is no child-porn or similar stuff) but I cannnot be sure that there are no f.e., nudes anywhere. So to be on the safe side i could change to: nude pictures on laptops traveling to iran. Do you think that is better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry! **They don't check anything in your laptop or personal electronic devices in Iran**. For safety reasons (not just for Iran but anywhere else) keep your devices in the cabin baggage and always beside yourself and of course insert some credentials for logging into them.

Enjoy your travel in Iran :)

Comment: I could also enter without any problems. Thx

Answer (score 6):

Do not worry. it is your private life. and in Islam people are free to do anything in private and officials are not allowed to search private life of people. the only possibility is if you are arrested as a spy that in that case still those pictures are your private life. in Islam a  human is free and can do sin privately (although is banned by God but still a human is free to go to Hell). the laws are for in public. not for private life. please note Wahhabism and Saudi tribe laws are different. in Iran the Shia Islam laws are used. and in Saudi tribe Wahhabism is used. also do not believe any Islamophobia and Iranophobia propaganda. there are many hands working to people do not learn about twelver shia Islam.

Comment: Even in Saudi customs has better things to do than pore over your laptop, they're mostly looking for alcohol. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21630/can-i-bring-an-anti-religious-book-into-saudi-arabia